# Normalize Pandas DataFrame at specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, data-science

i have a Pandas DataFrame with the following structure.

```
Feature 1  | Feature 2  | Feature 3
10         | 200        | True
30         | 233        | False
45         | 344        | True
```

any idea how i can do normalization for **feature 1** and **feature 2** only? without changing the index of original DataFrame.

i already try this following code, but it's normalize all columns and change the index of dataframe to 0,1,2

```
x = df.values
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
dataset = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a view of your dataframe:

```
x = df[['Feature 1', 'Feature 2']]
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
dataset = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
dataset['Feature 3'] = df['Feature 3']
```

Comment: it's work, but i have to include 'feature 3'  too (without normalization) in new dataset.

Comment: check the update (notice that your sample data has no index, so it should work)